# What happen if __init__() missing in subclass?

Tags: python, inheritance, constructor

Assume there are two classes A and B, and B inherited from A. A contains a __ init __ method and other methods, and B is missing a **init** method. If I called B with parameter, Where the parameter pass to? Does object B use __ init __ in parent class A?

Comment: How about you try it and see it for yourself? It's really simple to code.

Answer (score 2):

Methods are *inherited* from parent classes. Unless you override a method in a child class (by redefining it there), the parent's method implementation is used. This goes for all *all* methods, including `__init__`.

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        print('foo')

class Bar(Foo):
    pass

Bar()  # outputs 'foo'
```